Android Jetpack Compose Blank TextField for Integer, my solution works, but will it cause issues (database and view model)?
I looked at several things related to this and didn't find a solution that worked, so I figured out a work-around by playing around. I want to know if this will be OK, or if it is something that, maybe there's a right way to do this.
What I'm working on is a database app for myself (using Room). One of the entry values is a Quantity, which is an Int. Thing is, going to my "add entry" screen, the default value is a O in the text field, and clicking on it to enter a number is annoying because half the time, the entered number gets added to the 0... like if I click the box and hit "2", then the number is "20" and I have to erase the 0.
So I looked up having a blank text input for integers and just looking at what I was doing with the VIewModel and stuff, I figured "hey, what if I can just add a comma here and copy this changed value to two different values at once?" and... well it worked? What I did was add an additional val to the DataClass in the view model that was set to a type String with a blank string. Then I just changed the "onchange value" to copy the value to both the new value and to the one being used in the database with .toIntOrNull.
This new added val (squantity) is not one used in the database, it's only used for this field (display).
I haven't seen this particular thing in any of my searching and it has me wondering why (everything talks about using Radix and validation). Which, I probably should add Radix value at least just to be on the safe side (in the event a keyboard doesn't recognize the IME asks, that way no non-number characters get entered accidentally).
I tested it and it mostly works (just one minor problem which I think is solved). It added the item correctly to the Database and returned to the list screen so long as I entered some number in the field, and the entered number matches.
The exception in testing was if I left the field blank. The first time I did, the app crashed, but when I re-load it, the entry was entered into the database with a quantity of 0. I tried this a few times and sometimes the entry got added without a crash, sometimes it did crash, but regardless of what I put as a default integer (Data Class ItemDetails in View Model), it always gets added with a quantity of 0 and then I noticed I had my to int copy as "toIntOrNull() ?: 1" on the UI code page. I swapped that 1 to a 0 and now it seems to work without crashing and saves the default value (currently set to 1) entered in the ViewModel as the quantity when the field is left blank when saving a new entry.
I also added to the final function "squantity = quantity.toString()" (converts the Database table to the Data Class) and this seems to have worked, the existing quantity value now gets passed in to the field when I click an item to go to the Edit Entry screen.
Well really I have 2 questions...

Is this OK?
I was planning on maybe implementing +/- buttons to
increase/decrease the value in that field (would make updating
quantity easier if I add or use things up, the "edity entry" screen
uses the same body as the "add entry" screen), would this
potentially prevent me from doing that? I'm sure I can write some
logic code that if the field is blank, it assumes 0 and adds 1.

So, here's the relevant textfield code for my Add Entry screen (UI):
TextField(
    value = itemDetails.squantity,
    onValueChange = {
        onValueChange(itemDetails.copy(squantity = it, quantity = it.toIntOrNull() ?: 0))
                     },
    modifier = Modifier
        .width(54.dp),
    visualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None,
    enabled = true,
    singleLine = true,
    textStyle = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(textAlign = TextAlign.End),
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number),
)

And here's the relevant ViewModel behind, including converting this data class with the string value added at the end of the list in the details. The value exists only in Data Class ItemDetails and isn't copied to the functions that converts the item details to Items (database table), but is added to the Items (database table) to Item Details function.
data class ItemUiState(
    val itemDetails: ItemDetails = ItemDetails(),
    val isEntryValid: Boolean = false
)

data class ItemDetails(
    val id: Int = 0,
    val brand: String = "",
    val blend: String = "",
    val type: String = "",
    val quantity: Int = 1,
    val hated: Boolean = false,
    val squantity: String = ""
)


/** convert ItemDetails to Items (Database Table) **/
fun ItemDetails.toItem(): Items = Items(
    id = id,
    brand = brand,
    blend = blend,
    type = type,
    quantity = quantity,
    hated = hated
)

/** convert Items to ItemUiState**/
fun Items.toItemUiState(isEntryValid: Boolean = false): ItemUiState = ItemUiState(
    itemDetails = this.toItemDetails(),
    isEntryValid = isEntryValid
)

/** convert Items (Database) to ItemDetails (Data Class) **/
fun Items.toItemDetails(): ItemDetails = ItemDetails(
    id = id,
    brand = brand,
    blend = blend,
    type = type,
    quantity = quantity,
    hated = hated,
    squantity = quantity.toString()
)


Just a quick comment. I did a lot of testing without there being crashes, but I decided to see if I could get away with one value. I set the TextField to be "quantity" rather than "squantity" and set "quantity" to be a string in the data class, then changed the "quantity" in the VM fuction that converts the data class values to the data base table "Items" to be "quantity = quantity.toIntOrNull..." (the inverse of the last function that converts the table items to data), and that worked some, but caused app crashes. I didn't check to see what the crash was.
